Powerpoint: Loop an animation with delays between the repeats
Now before we start: I am aware that this is basically a duplicate of this question:
Loop object animation with pause between each repeat ,
but since the question was made in 2013 im kind of hoping that there might be a better solution by now. Especially since the answer to that question, whilst still being the only solution I can see so far, is EXTREMLY convaluted.
But now lets get to the meat of the question.
To use an easy example: Lets say we have a object on the right of the slide and another on the left. For the sake of ease I will now refer to the objects as R and L whilst refering to the orignal right and left positions as RP and LP.
What I want to do is:
When the slide starts we only see R on RP.
When the animation is triggered with a simple click I want

R to move to LP.
R becomes invisible
L becomes visible at LP.
L moves to RP.
L becomes invisible
R becomes visible at RP (Ido NOT want to show an animation of R moving back to RP).

Repeat steps 1-6 until the next click, after which both R and L then disappear.
Now this sounds rather simple but the problem is: as far as I can see there is no option to add delays between the repeats.So lets say we have an animation that is set to repeat until the next click with a delay of 1.5 seconds and a duration of 0.5 seconds, what happens is that yes initially it waits for 1.5 seconds before starting the animation, but after that it will just repeat the animation after it has run meaning every 0.5 seconds. Which is of course not what I want.
So the Question can be imagined as twofold:

What would be the optimal way to get the sequence I described.
Is there a way to comfortably add delays between repeats, without using audio Bookmarks.

Now in general Im more interested in question 2 personally BUT question 1 is more important.
I And also I would like to keep this on ONE slide. I mention this becuase some approaches I found run on repeating a slide, but that is not an option for me, since this sequence is one of many animation on that slide and its by far not at the beginning.
But Id be open to possible add-ins that might be helpfull, if "vanilla" powerpoint cant get the job done.
Now at first I tried the aformentioned "just add delay" approach and I described why that didnt work.
After that (with admitingly heavy GPT advice) I tried to add exit/entrance animations between the motions and played with the delays and durations in that, hoping that the repeat might also respect the "Start after previous" setting, where my Idea was that it would only repeat after the previous step also repeated, but nope. Its just a giant free for all.
After that I tried too look for ways of using the Bookmark approach without needing to do a recording. But I found none.

Edit:
Now did manage to get my lets say "desired Result", without being able to use loops but instead doing this multiple times.
So Instead of having my permanent loop I just did one animation of R moving to LP and vanishing while L then appears and moves to RP and vanishes. I then just copy Pasted both objects a couple times  (added the appear animation so they dont shown all at once) and then I need to manually position them to all have the same starting point.
So basically I now have

R1 moving to LP
R1 vanishes
L1 appears
L1 moves to RP
L1 vanishes
R2 appears
R2 moves to LP

and so on
now this ofc does/shows what I want, but its kind of tedious and also limits me to only being able to "repeat/loop" the movements as many times as I copy paste them. This also results in me readding the same pictures many times bloating the File and the Selection Pane. So in short I now have something that works but I really dont like the approach. Now maybe this is the "optimal approach" I asked for, and if so feel free to tell me that it is, but Id be very happy if future answers could recommend something different.
